# Why does an embeded dropdown only choose the first option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, node.js

I have a page that contains an html page rendered using node with express and ejs. In the page is a html table that has a select dropdown in one of the cells.  **The dropdown populates correctly with the correct values**

The problem is no matter what I choose from the drop down the selected table row is always the first row only.  In other words if there are 7 rows in the table and I change the value in the dropdown of the 3rd row the changes are applied to the first row not the third.  I hope this is clear enough to understand.

This is the code for the html table

```
<% 
var j1=jobs.j1;j2=jobs.j2;j3=jobs.j3;j4=jobs.j4;j5=jobs.j5;
j6=jobs.j6;j7=jobs.j7;j8=jobs.j8;j9=jobs.j9;j10=jobs.j10;

if (j1 >0) {job1=job[0].JobName;}
if (j2 >0) {job2=job[1].JobName;}
if (j3 >0) {job3=job[2].JobName;}
if (j4 >0) {job4=job[3].JobName;}
if (j5 >0) {job5=job[4].JobName;}
if (j6 >0) {job6=job[5].JobName;}
if (j7 >0) {job7=job[6].JobName;}
if (j8 >0) {job8=job[7].JobName;}
if (j9 >0) {job9=job[8].JobName;}
if (j10 >0) {job10=job[9].JobName;}  
%>

<% if (j1 > 0) {
%>
<table align='left' border='1' ; style='font-size:16px;width:100%'>
<tr>
<th >Nxt</th>  
<th align='left'  style='background-color: #00b0e6;'><%= job1 %></th>
<th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Employee </th>
<th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Status </th>
<th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Emp ID</th>
</tr>
<%
for (var i in taskrows) {
  if (taskrows[i].JobID == j1){
    var task = taskrows[i].Task;
    var emp = taskrows[i].Employee;
    var status = taskrows[i].Status;
    var emp_id = taskrows[i].EmpID;
    var id = taskrows[i].ID;
%>

<tr>
  <td width='5%'><Button style="height:20px; width:30px;"></button></td>
  <td width='40%'><%= task %></td>
  <td align='center' width='5%'>
  <select name='emp' class='emp' onChange='getEmp();' >
  <option value='' selected='selected'><%=emp%></option>

<% for (var i in emprows) {
    var emp = emprows[i].Alias;
    var empid = emprows[i].Emp_ID;
%>
<option value='<%= empid %>'><%= emp %></option>
<%}%>
<input type="hidden" id="id" value=<%=id%>>
</select>
</td>
<td align='center' width='15%'>
<select name='stat' onchange=''>
<option value='' selected='selected'>Not Scheduled</option>
  <% for (var i in statrows) {
    var stat = statrows[i].Status;
    var statid = statrows[i].ID;

  %>
 <option value='<%= statid %>'><%= stat %></option>
 <%}%>
 </select>
 </td>

 <td align='center' width='10%'><%= emp_id %></td>

 </tr>

<%}
}%>
```

and the javascript

```
<script>
function getEmp(){ 

$(".emp").change(function(){
var emp_id =  $(".emp option:selected").attr('value'); 
var id = $("#id").val();
console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'getemp',
        data: {emp_id: emp_id, id: id},
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });

};
```

router:

```
router.get('/getemp', function(req, res, next) {
intake.getEmp(req.query, function(data){
res.end;
});
});
```

route

```
Intake.getEmp = function(query, cb){
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : '******',
password : '*****',
database : '*********',
});
connection.connect();
var empid = parseInt(query.emp_id);
var id = parseInt(query.id);
var empString = 'SELECT Alias FROM employees WHERE Emp_ID =?';
var insert = [empid];
empString =mysql.format(empString, insert);
connection.query(empString, function(err, empdata, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var emp = empdata[0].Alias;

var queryString = 'UPDATE inv_line_item SET EmpID=?, Employee=? WHERE  ID=?';
var inserts = [empid, emp, id]
queryString = mysql.format(queryString, inserts);
connection.query(queryString, function(err, nothing, fields) {

  if (err) throw err;
  });
});
};
```

what should happen is when an employee is picked from the drop down the selected employee should be assigned to the task that appears in the table row.  What happens is the employee is assigned to the first row regardless of which row the select box is in.  Does that help make things clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate instance using `this` within the event handler.

```
$(".emp").change(function(){
   // "this" is the select that was changed
   var emp_id =  $(this).val();

   /* your ajax code left out for clarity*/
});
```

The problem you are having is that `$(".emp option:selected")` will return *all* selected `<option>` within *all* `class="emp"` that exist in the page.

Since only one value can be returned it will be the value of the first matching element in the selector

Comment: @charliefl I thin I was unclear.  The dropdown selects the correct item from the list but regardless of which row the drop down is in within the tabel the first row is the one affected.

Comment: affected by what? All you show is `console.log()` in ajax success. Where is code that is doing any DOM modification?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more information

Comment: what does `assigned to first row` mean? Is problem in client side? What is `$('#id')` and is that ID duplicated in page? You are not being specific enough about what the specific issue is

Comment: see above in the OP the html shows a hidden text input with an id="id" this is just getting to difficult here I must be dense as no one seems to understand what I am saying

Comment: Well you just haven't identified the behavior that is unexpected... table could be db table or html table and there is no code shown that would manipulate and html table

Comment: got if figured out and if you look above at my original post you will see that the first sentence says I am dealing with a webpage that has a html table.  Anyway thank for the input , also if you look at the edit I made you will see that it routes out to perform an update query on the database.  Fixed and resolved if anyone is interested in the solution I'd be happy to post it.

Comment: no point posting a solution when the problem isn't even clear

Comment: kindly remove me from this country club!

Answer (score 0):

Your issues I believe is how you are using your selector and generating your HTML for the ID.  you set each input to the ID of id and then do a general select on it, which will get the first instance of it even though you are acting on a different record.  You could just set the ID as a data attribute on the select rather than on another hidden input and then just get the data attribute value to fill in your JSON data you are feeding back rather then generically selecting the "#id" field.  This would actually be better anyway since you have that select html object on the change event and don't have to go back to the DOM to fidden a different element as you are doing now.  Just add a attribute to your option tag which would be the element selected on the option that you are already selecting to get the emp id off of:

```
<option value='<%= empid %>' **data-attr-id='<%= id %>'**><%= emp %></option>
```

Then you can use a standard get attribute call to get the id assocaited with the currently selected element since you are already selecting the option in the change event.

```
function getEmp(){ 

$(".emp").change(function(){
var optionElement = $("option:selected", this);
var empId = this.value;
var id = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-attr-id');

console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'getemp',
        data: {emp_id: emp_id, id: id},
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });

};
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp Hope this helps.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/r4s2c0m7/1/

Comment: could you be so kind as to show me in code an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Updated the answer to be more specific.  Many ways to handle. Tried to give you one approach.  GL.